# Admin-on-rest: How can you expand the size of ReferenceInput and AutocompleteInput input fields?

Tags: admin-on-rest

How can you expand the size of ReferenceInput and AutocompleteInput fields in admin on rest?

```
<Create title="My title" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput label= "field 1" source="f1"  validate={[ required, minLength(3), maxLength(20) ]} />
        <ReferenceInput label="field 2" source="f2" validate={[ required ]} reference="reference1" allowEmpty>
            <AutocompleteInput optionText="f3" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

[Image: Default field size in red. Desired size in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcXiM.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can pass styles to the underlying Material UI component using the elStyle and options props.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html